# How to secure the JSON data that's being passed from the AJAX file to jqGrid

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, jqgrid

First of all, thank you so very much for making jqGrid!  It's an excellent piece of work!

When my index.php file POSTs the JSON-encoded search criteria to my grid.php file, grid.php processes the criteria, queries the database, and returns a JSON-encoded string back to index.php, which in turn takes the results and renders them in a jqGrid table.

Everything works splendidly.

However, if an in-house user points their browser to grid.php, it will return a set of records that satisfies the default criteria (30 records per page, the fields and their data, as programmed).  And because I have it setup to POST, a user could append query parameters manually to grid.php, e.g.:

```
    http://foo.bar/grid.php?clientID=123&city=anytown
```

I've placed security checks in both my index.php and grid.php. As an example:

```
    if(userGroup='Sales'){
       $sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE group='SALES'";
    }else{
       $sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM table";
    }
```

But the problem is that they can bypass these checks by pointing their browser to grid.php directly.

Does anyone have suggestions of how to secure the string that's returned by grid.php?

**UPDATE**

Per Justin's suggestion, I think that I might be on the right path now.  Something like this might work:

```
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    if ($trace[0]['file'] != 'index.php'){
       echo "There was an error. Please contact your Systems Administrator.";
       return 0;
    }
```

Well, that didn't work as expected.  I'm leaving this info here for posterity.

Comment: How are you getting $userGroup?  I suspect you might be looking for sessions.  You aren't doing something like &usergroup=Sales are you?

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER build SQL statements on the client. Always use validated parameters and do it on the server.

Comment: I am using sessions, and userGroup is being sent from index.php via postData.  However, I'm not sure how that would mitigate what grid.php send back to index.php.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, I'm not building my queries like that.  That was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add PHP code to secure the grid.php URL. First, if it is feasible for your application, you can add an authentication system to prevent just any users from accessing the URL. Once that is in place, you could secure it even more by adding role-based or user-based permissions.

For example, only allow the user group of "sales" to be appended if the user provides that option and they are a member of the "sales" group.

How you will actually implement this depends up on what PHP framework you are using (if any) and the requirements of your application.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you so much for the advice!  So password protecting that file via .htaccess won't work, but your suggestion gave me a direction to go with this.  I inherited this CRM, and its not built on any kind of framework, but surely there has to be a way to code in something like: "If ./index.php is calling me, then respond. Otherwise output an error."  Now to figure out *how* to do that.  I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: Hmm... you really would be better off using data from the session to do this checking, if the right data is (or can be made available). For example, if you can say `if ($_SESSION['role_permissions]['sales']) { ... }`. But obviously that involves larger changes to the application.

Comment: Good call.  While the changes might be more involved, I think it's a workable solution.  I'll give that shot.  Thanks a brazillion!